# Optimize import data from one table into another

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-performance, merge

Edited on mustaccio request.

I have simple table:

```
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.objects;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.objects
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('objects_id_seq'::regclass),
    value text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    key text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    is_valid boolean DEFAULT false
) PARTITION BY LIST (is_valid);

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.objects
    OWNER to postgres;
-- Index: key_idx

-- DROP INDEX IF EXISTS public.key_idx;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS key_idx
    ON public.objects USING btree
    (key COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
;
-- Index: id_idx

-- DROP INDEX IF EXISTS public.id_idx;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS id_idx
    ON public.objects USING btree
    (id ASC NULLS LAST)
;
-- Index: value_idx

-- DROP INDEX IF EXISTS public.value_idx;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS value_idx
    ON public.objects USING btree
    (value COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
;

-- Partitions SQL

CREATE TABLE public.objects_with_valid PARTITION OF public.objects
    FOR VALUES IN (true)
    PARTITION BY LIST (lower("left"(value, 1)))
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.objects_with_valid
    OWNER to postgres;
    
CREATE TABLE public.objects_without_valid PARTITION OF public.objects
    FOR VALUES IN (false)
    PARTITION BY LIST (lower("left"(value, 1)))
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.objects_without_valid
    OWNER to postgres;
```

with 92M+ rows. Selecting is quite fast, WHERE around 0.06 sec LIKE around 0.2 sec

Then i imported data to temporary table (around 500K rows). I want to insert data from temp table into production one. But method that I use is extremly slow.

```
MERGE INTO table ca
USING temptable t
ON t.value = ca.value and t.key = ca.key
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (value, key, is_valid)
  VALUES (t.value, t.key, true);
```

EXPLAIN for above:

```
"Merge on objects ca  (cost=40500054.86..42121761.54 rows=0 width=0)"
"  Merge on objects_with_0 ca_1"
"  Merge on objects_with_1 ca_2"
"  Merge on objects_with_2 ca_3"
"  Merge on objects_with_3 ca_4"
"  Merge on objects_with_4 ca_5"
"  Merge on objects_with_5 ca_6"
"  Merge on objects_with_6 ca_7"
"  Merge on objects_with_7 ca_8"
"  Merge on objects_with_8 ca_9"
"  Merge on objects_with_9 ca_10"
"  Merge on objects_with_a ca_11"
"  Merge on objects_with_b ca_12"
"  Merge on objects_with_c ca_13"
"  Merge on objects_with_d ca_14"
"  Merge on objects_with_e ca_15"
"  Merge on objects_with_f ca_16"
"  Merge on objects_with_g ca_17"
"  Merge on objects_with_h ca_18"
"  Merge on objects_with_i ca_19"
"  Merge on objects_with_j ca_20"
"  Merge on objects_with_k ca_21"
"  Merge on objects_with_l ca_22"
"  Merge on objects_with_m ca_23"
"  Merge on objects_with_n ca_24"
"  Merge on objects_with_o ca_25"
"  Merge on objects_with_p ca_26"
"  Merge on objects_with_q ca_27"
"  Merge on objects_with_r ca_28"
"  Merge on objects_with_s ca_29"
"  Merge on objects_with_t ca_30"
"  Merge on objects_with_u ca_31"
"  Merge on objects_with_v ca_32"
"  Merge on objects_with_w ca_33"
"  Merge on objects_with_x ca_34"
"  Merge on objects_with_y ca_35"
"  Merge on objects_with_z ca_36"
"  Merge on objects_with_default ca_37"
"  ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=40500054.86..42121761.54 rows=92459232 width=31)"
"        Merge Cond: ((t.value = ca.value) AND (t.key = ca.key))"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=19611819.49..19842967.57 rows=92459232 width=21)"
"              Sort Key: t.value, t.key"
"              ->  Seq Scan on tempemails t  (cost=0.00..1689976.32 rows=92459232 width=21)"
"        ->  Materialize  (cost=20888235.37..21349648.96 rows=92282717 width=31)"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=20888235.37..21118942.17 rows=92282717 width=31)"
"                    Sort Key: ca.value, ca.key"
"                    ->  Append  (cost=0.00..2055626.75 rows=92282717 width=31)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_0 ca_1  (cost=0.00..777.18 rows=45418 width=31)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_1 ca_2  (cost=0.00..2561.07 rows=151407 width=30)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_2 ca_3  (cost=0.00..1427.53 rows=84653 width=29)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_3 ca_4  (cost=0.00..937.78 rows=56378 width=27)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_4 ca_5  (cost=0.00..853.42 rows=51242 width=27)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_5 ca_6  (cost=0.00..670.16 rows=40216 width=27)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_6 ca_7  (cost=0.00..521.06 rows=31206 width=27)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_7 ca_8  (cost=0.00..590.27 rows=35327 width=27)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_8 ca_9  (cost=0.00..515.52 rows=30752 width=27)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_9 ca_10  (cost=0.00..479.70 rows=28670 width=28)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_a ca_11  (cost=0.00..131448.62 rows=7602062 width=32)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_b ca_12  (cost=0.00..81150.92 rows=4700792 width=31)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_c ca_13  (cost=0.00..101959.91 rows=5871091 width=32)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_d ca_14  (cost=0.00..83177.18 rows=4819218 width=31)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_e ca_15  (cost=0.00..57243.55 rows=3315255 width=31)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_f ca_16  (cost=0.00..42702.34 rows=2466034 width=32)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_g ca_17  (cost=0.00..57396.93 rows=3321793 width=31)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_h ca_18  (cost=0.00..44526.97 rows=2579897 width=31)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_i ca_19  (cost=0.00..31954.73 rows=1852873 width=31)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_j ca_20  (cost=0.00..110328.16 rows=6384516 width=31)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_k ca_21  (cost=0.00..74663.27 rows=4339927 width=31)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_l ca_22  (cost=0.00..92877.07 rows=5369207 width=31)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_m ca_23  (cost=0.00..156545.37 rows=9049237 width=32)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_n ca_24  (cost=0.00..48544.22 rows=2814722 width=31)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_o ca_25  (cost=0.00..20505.73 rows=1193873 width=31)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_p ca_26  (cost=0.00..67841.19 rows=3923819 width=32)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_q ca_27  (cost=0.00..3265.34 rows=190334 width=31)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_r ca_28  (cost=0.00..74204.71 rows=4295571 width=31)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_s ca_29  (cost=0.00..132988.34 rows=7689234 width=32)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_t ca_30  (cost=0.00..68148.51 rows=3949151 width=31)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_u ca_31  (cost=0.00..7068.79 rows=412379 width=31)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_v ca_32  (cost=0.00..30176.51 rows=1746351 width=31)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_w ca_33  (cost=0.00..27847.93 rows=1613693 width=31)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_x ca_34  (cost=0.00..10339.96 rows=595496 width=32)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_y ca_35  (cost=0.00..15530.14 rows=902014 width=31)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_z ca_36  (cost=0.00..12222.85 rows=715885 width=30)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on objects_with_default ca_37  (cost=0.00..220.24 rows=13024 width=29)"
"                                Filter: is_valid"
"JIT:"
"  Functions: 196"
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
```

I use db inside docker:
PostgreSQL 15.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 12.2.1_git20220924-r10) 12.2.1 20220924, 64-bit

host:
CPU i7 4 core
Ram 16GB 2133
Storage 256GB ssd

How to optimize process?

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 0):

An EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) would be better, showing the real time elapsed, but I think the biggest problem is your MERGE is not taking advantage of any index or partition and is instead gathering and re-sorting all 92M rows before even starting to compare to the temporary table.

I would suggest trying something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table ca (value, key, is_valid)
SELECT t.value, t.key, true
FROM temptable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
      (SELECT 1 FROM table ca2 
       WHERE ca2.value=t.value AND ca2.key=t.key 
             AND lower(left(ca2.value, 1)) = lower(left(t.value, 1)))
```

The last WHERE condition is to ensure that for every row in temptable only the matching partition will be searched.

Also, having separate indexes on key and value is not useful for this use case.
Check if you can replace the key one with a composite index:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS key_value_idx
    ON public.objects USING btree
    (key COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST, value COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST);
```